# Reading Error Information

Tags: google-apps-script, error-correction

How do I see more details on the error messages I get when running scripts inside a spreadsheet (or anywhee for that matter). For example; when getting  a 'red failed script' message it only highlights it in red and gives a link to Dismiss. I want to get more information on the error for debugging and troublshooting.

Is there some facility to view this information?

If not what is the typical troubleshooting method used to drill down into the error and figure out exactly what is causing it to better find a solution?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to open the Script Editor in the spreadsheet so you can look at the script itself.  Select the function you are trying to run in the spreadsheet from the dropdown thingy at the top and hit the play button.  It should give you a reason and a line number where it fails.  Place a breakpoint there and hit the debug button and step through it.